# You like them hats?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion

Last year around Christmas time [arQAde](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) had a little promotion in which they awarded hats for gravatars for completing basic tasks around the site.

[Here's a link](http://stackexchange.com/promos/2/hat-dash) to the promo from last year (and a [blog post](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/)).

[image]

[image]

This year, SE is planning to run it across all the sites - **but wait**!

For this promo to kickoff, each site community has to **opt in**. And there's where this meta post comes in - vote up the answer(yay/nay), or drop a comment if you want Super User to be part of this promo.

Note that this promotion is **optional** for the **sites, and/or individual users**. If the users of this site *do not* want this in general feel free to voice that opinion. We can opt out of the promotion.

If the community Individual users will be able to opt out as well (they will be provided with an "I hate Hats" link to opt out once the promo starts).

Comment: note: Please upvote the relevant answer to indicate your support towards the opinion!

Comment: So... WHEN CAN I HAZ HATZ!?!?!?!?!?!?

Answer (score 53):

Yes! We Super Users like hats and want more of them! Yay to the hat dash promo!

Comment: yay hats like in tf2 :P

Comment: @HackToHell: No, I want Super User-y hats! Perhaps Oliver can help with his CSS skills...

Comment: FREE HAT!⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣

Comment: Gentlemen. *whistles as he downvotes*

Comment: We should get a hat that relates to sudo or root :)

Comment: I can't use the hats but for my friends vote goes to **YES WE NEED HATS**.

Comment: …wait. How does this work? If we _want_ hats, do we upvote the yes answer and downvote the no answer? Why does the no answer have a negative amount of votes? If you're against hats, do you _downvote_ the _no_ answer instead of upvoting it? \*is very confused\*

Comment: @BlacklightShining I think people are so excited about their hats they want to eliminate any possibility that they won't get them.

Comment: @BlacklightShining Usually when voting like this, we'll just count the upvotes on the answers.

Comment: Hats! Hats! Hats@!

Comment: Yes, a "sudo su" hat seems to be in order here.

Answer (score -13):

No! We Super Users hate hats! We want no hats! Nay to the hat dash promo!