# Winter bash hats in user profile don't support window resizing

Tags: bug, status-declined, user-profiles, winter-bash

The [hat](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5878/you-like-them-hats) in users' profiles does not move with the centered page contents (including the gravatar) when the browser window is resized.

Demo in Firefox (Safari has the same issue), before and after resizing the browser window:

[image: Correct hat position]

[image: Wrong hat position]

Comment: Hats off to you for finding this bug!

Comment: well with winterbash ending tomorrow, it's going to go the too localized route

Comment: @Sathya Assuming it's not a regular or recurring event. That's why I reported this, I don't believe this was the last hat event on SE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an error we were aware of but deemed too minor to fix. Simply reloading the javascript on the page resolved the error (that is, a refesh) so it didn't need a full fix.

I'm marking this [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) but it's really more [status-acknowledged](/questions/tagged/status-acknowledged).

Comment: Why mark it as 'status-declined'? Surely the 'status-acknowledged' is more appropriate (as you said)?